# Control+backspace in textbox javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I have a requirement of having a text-box with default value say "PF_". If I type something and press control+backspace All the values are been deleted. This problem occurs only If I have an underscore "_" at the end.

**Javascript**

```
var readOnlyLength = $('#field').val().length;
$('#output').text(readOnlyLength);
$('#field').on('keypress, keydown', function (event) {
    var $field = $(this);
    $('#output').text(event.which + '-' + this.selectionStart);
    if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39)) && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength) || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Html**

```
<input id="field" type="text" value="PF_" size="50" />
```

I have tried a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hx7dak0/).

Any Idea?

Comment: Try `keypress keydown` instead of `keypress, keydown`.

Comment: Same result @RejithRKrishnan

Comment: Same result with space char.

Comment: Only with underscore '_' at the End deletes all the texts. Does not work with `keypress keydown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but this will reset the field to the previous value if the user tries to modify the read-only part:

```
$('#field').on('keypress, keydown', function (event) {
    var $field = $(this);
    var old = $field.val();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($field.val().slice(0,3)!='PF_') {
            $field.val(old);
        }
    },0);
});
```

Edit: in response to op's comments, try this code instead:

```
$('#field').on('keypress, keydown', function (event) {
    var $field = $(this);
    if(event.ctrlKey && event.which==8) { // ctrl-backspace
        $field.val('PF_');
        return false;
    }
    var old = $field.val();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($field.val().slice(0,3)!='PF_') {
            $field.val(old);
        }
    },0);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hx7dak0/20/)

Comment: Nice one. But This is not I was looking for. I dont want the previous value when control+bkspce. The values should be deleted.

Comment: Edited my answer; is the new fiddle what you want?: http://jsfiddle.net/2hx7dak0/18/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("#field").keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val().length < 3){
        $(this).val("PF_");
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hcufx3qh/)